# I would like to insert an pre-loaded image into a google document depending on a result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am a rusty programmer, and sort of new to javascript, though I am learning a lot from these forums (thank you all for so much sharing).

I have a survey in google that people fill out.  This generates two particular scores, the first being a risk score, and the second being a function score.  The scores have a range of normal to "high risk".

I have a report that is generated and emailed to the client upon submitting the form.  Currently, the form report the risk score in terms of x / 8, and the function score as y / 24, along with the boring wordy legend of what that means.

I am trying to dress it up by adding a graphic representation.

For example, if the function score is out of 24, and their score is somewhere between 0-6, they are considered normal.  I'd like to have a graphic bar, green on one end, yellow between 7-10, orange between 11-18 and red from 18 onwards, and an arrow or a black line through the important area.  I was thinking I would just have 25 (0-24) images, with the same bar, and the marker just incrementally further up the scale as needed.  They would be named:

ESS0.png, ESS1.png, etc.

What I would like to do is based on my variable epworthScore

if (epworthScore == 0) {DISPLAY IMAGE ESS0.png;}
if (epworthScore == 1) {DISPLAY IMAGE ESS1.png;}

...

I don't know if there is a sleeker way of doing this, nor how to take that image (which will be located on my home google drive).  I don't know how to put a marker for it in my report template.  I am using "keyVARIABLE" as a place holder for my numeric values and using copyBody.ReplaceText command to insert my numbers.  I don't know the equivalent to placing graphics.

Any help would be appreciated.

A picture is worth a thousand words, right?

Thank you,

Robin

Comment: I've retagged your question, as it seems not be related to java, but javascript. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211434/insert-image-into-a-specified-location), I think it will give you enough information to do what you want, just add some logic to select the right image ;-)